# System Preferences keep auto-opening in Finder Extensions view

Tags: macos, system-settings

I recently bought a Mac Studio and transferred data from my older Mac mini. The Studio is running macOS 12.6.1, but for the past month or two so (starting when it was running 12.5 or 12.6), I’ve been noticing an odd issue. (The Mac mini is still on Catalina and has never had the issue. My MacBook Pro is on 12.6.1 as well and also does not have the issue.)

The issue is that at seemingly random times, perhaps once or twice a day, my System Preferences will suddenly open on its own (or if it’s already open in the background, jump to the front) and interrupt whatever I’m doing at the time.

It always opens to the same view, namely *Extensions* → *Finder Extensions*:

[image: The image that pops up]

It always looks exactly like this: the OneDrive extension is not enabled, but there’s a little blue dot next to it (like it’s newly installed?).

I do have Office 2019 installed, but I have never knowingly installed anything to do with OneDrive, which I don’t use – and of course, I’m not even sure the OneDrive extension actually has anything to do with this to begin with.

I haven’t been able to identify any common denominators at all when this happens. It’s happened while using an Internet browser, InDesign, VSCode, Excel – and it also happens when I’m not even at the computer at all.

**What could be causing this odd behaviour?** And how can I get rid of it.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue and from your screenshot it seems we only have the Google Drive extension in common. So I disabled auto-start for Google Drive and closed it.
Now I can reproduce the issue: every time I start Google Drive manually, the system prefs dialog comes up again, which seems to confirm it is causing this behaviour. It's probably triggering the system prefs dialog also every time it checks for updates or so.

I do not have a solution to fix this, though. I just keep Google Drive off by default, not using it much anyway and probably even less in the future...

Comment: Thanks for the detective work! Unfortunately, I use Google Drive constantly, so I can’t turn it off, but it’s good to know at least that that’s the culprit.